# Better algorithm for a multi-variable gambling puzzle than brute force?

Tags: algorithm, gambling

I don't know the name to describe the problem, so I'm just going to set up an example of it and ask for help with an algorithm better than brute force to solve.

There are 6 buckets, each one a different size, each one holding a different starting volume.  Each bucket also has a link to a prize value - call it money - that is dispensed when the bucket is full.

There are 8 valves.  Each valve feeds a different subset of buckets when opened, and each bucket can get a different amount added when the valve is opened.  Each valve has a fixed cost to turn.

Partial Example: 
Bucket 1: 14 of 20 gallons.  Pays $2.00
Bucket 2: 12 of 25 gallons.  Pays $1.50
Bucket 3: 18 of 35 gallons.  Pays $4.00
etc...

Valve 1: Costs $0.50.  puts 2 gallons in 2 and 1 gallon in 3.
Valve 2: Costs $0.40.  Puts 3 gals in 1 and 5 gals in 2
etc...

So you pay some money to turn a valve, and if you fill a bucket you win some money.

Objective: Calculate the best order of valves to turn to net the most profit when the buckets fill up, if any profitable combinations exist.

When a bucket is full, it resets to a pre-set starting volume (which may be different than its current volume - buckets retain state from valve turn to valve turn).  Theoretically there is no limit to the number of resets so one could potentially turn valves forever.

The OBVIOUS solution here is brute force.  Reset your variables to start position, turn one valve, test the output, reset, iterate to the next valve, etc.  After all 8 are turned, start turning two valves (11, 12, 13, 14, ... 25, 26, 27, 28).  Every time you find a combination that fills at least one bucket, calculate the net gain/loss and compare against previous results to determine the best.

Slow and crude.  Fairly direct, but slow and crude.

So:

1. What is the name of this type of problem? and
2. Is there a known algorithm that helps solve it more efficiently?

To be clear - the math specifics aren't the bit that need improving - I can calculate the result of any sequence of valve operations easily regardless of minor variations in math.

It's the brute force iteration that I want to avoid.  I do not want to do 8 single operations (v1, v2, v3...), then 64 double operations (v1v1, v1v2, v1v3, etc...), then 512 triple operations (v1v1v1, v1v1v2, v1v1v3) if I can avoid it.

Comment: What happens if a valve dumps 2 gallons into a bucket with 24 of 25 gallons filled? Let's say that the pre-set starting volume is 0 (I don't really understand why this is a separate parameter when we can just vary the size of the bucket).

Comment: The pre-set starting volume isn't 0, and I think it's that way in order to make it harder to solve, to be quite frank.  However, it isn't the math itself I'm trying to solve - I know how to solve that.  It's the brute force iteration that I want to improve.  Whether overflowing the bucket resets it to the start or sets it to the start + the overflow amount is ultimately irrelevant.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo: Surely how it resets is important. In the extreme case if a tap dumped a million gallons into a 10 gallon bucket then if overflow was wasted you'd win once but if it carried over then you'd win 100,000 times. Clearly in a realistic situation it wouldn't be that bad but it may be that the best combination would involve repeatedly filling one bucket. As for solving, I'm not sure. It sounds a bit like a linear programming problem but I'm not sure how you would set it up to solve it as one.

Comment: Also as a note any solution will be best done if you rephrase the problem to eliminate the starting volumne. As David hinted at a 25 gallon bucket that always resets to 13 gallons is exactly the same as a 12 gallon bucket that resets to 0 gallons. So reform the problem to the latter to eliminate a whole lot of pointless data before you worry about solving it.

Comment: Well, there won't be a case where enough extra is dumped into a bucket to fill the bucket to overflowing twice - so you'll never get the 1 valve turn 100,000 bucket fills.  At most you'll get 1 valve turn, one fill with a slight increase to the reset starting amount.  That MIGHT affect the algorithm to determine what iterations would be redundant some, I agree, but what I'm looking for is a formula by which brute force iteration is replaced by something more efficient.

Comment: Let's rephrase the question: does the order of valve turns matter?

Comment: Ah!  Well, I suppose if the bucket resets to "start value" then no, but if it resets to "start value + overflow" then yes.  I believe, however, that they reset to "start value" without any overflow.  I will have to confirm.

Comment: After more testing, when the bucket overflows, the surplus is kept and passed onto the reset bucket.  This surprised me.